# React Bootstrap Layout

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

It's not complicated but I'm blinded.

I use, in my react project, react-bootstrap plugin.
For the responsive I following the documentation and I put breakpoints in my code.

With this code, I want to have a component responsive with 5 breakpoints. That is tottaly good in xl / lg and md but when I'm in sm, the breakpoint doesn't worked and the MD breakpoint eat the xs and sm breakpoints.

Just why ?

```
<Container fluid>
 <Row className="m-0">
  <Col xs={12} sm={10} md={8} lg={6} xl={4}  className="m-auto text-center side-left">
    
      <h1 className="text-uppercase title main-yellow"> Something</h1>
      <h2 className="text-uppercase main-brown"> Something </h2>
      <p className="p-5">
         Something else
      </p>

  </Col>
 </Row>
</Container>
```

Comment: Try this <Col  xl={4}  lg={6} md={8}  sm={10}  xs={12}  className="m-auto text-center side-left">

Comment: @Umesh thx for your reply, but that doesn't work. When I see templates in React-Bootstrap, they only doing the md and lg breapoints. The MD breakpoint is only for tablet and mobiles then they doing the same design for them. I will do this I think, I haven't others solutions